# Flask runs same request multiple times

Tags: python, http, flask, gunicorn

I have a Flask/Gunicorn backend running a machine learning process that takes around 20 minutes. There is a post request triggering the function and returning the output.

Everything works fine when I run the request through cURL, but when running the same request from the browser in the front-end, a few minutes into the request the same flask process starts again, without terminating the first one, where I end up running two requests simultaneausly which increases the run time.

What causes that? I know that cURL doesn't do the initial OPTIONS request, is it possible that OPTIONS triggers process before POST arrives?

Comment: Are you by any chance using Chrome?

Comment: Have you tried looking at the network tab to see if there is a timeout? Long running backgroud tasks should not be handled in the request context. You can use workers like redis or flask-executor  if you dont want a scalable application.

Comment: It keeps waiting for POST - I set all the timeouts to 0. I am going to move to something more scalable in the future but, for now, I need a simple temporary solution. Will have a look into Redis probably. Thanks

Comment: @roganjosh I tried both Firefox and Chrome - it appears in both

Comment: I don't think there is a clean approach to solve this if you have a long-running request because the browser will automatically re-issue the request if it doesn't get an initial response. That's why the suggestion by @Luv is important

Comment: @roganjosh. Does it mean the browser resends the POST request? I don't see record of it happening in NGINX or in Flask logs.